# Excel vba: non-contiguous cells within same row, and command

Tags: excel, vba

Im a vba noobie, please help. I have 3000 rows and 40 columns.

Starting from row 5 to last row, and only look at columns 8,11,14,17,20,23,26,29,32.

I need to write a code saying that if each cells in colummns 8,11,14,17,20,23,26,29,32 and are in same row are absolutely smaller and equal to 5, then make a comment at the cell (row,40)="OK IN PROGRESS"
If one of the cell(columns 8,11,14,17,20,23,26,29,32) in each same row is absolutely bigger and equal to 5, then at the cell(row,40)=(whichever columns that is bigger than 5)&"NOT IN PROGRESS"

Also I need to rename each column's number.

```
8=george
11=cindy
14=jennifer
17=lucas
20=apple
23=jeff
26=may
29=kevin
32=oscar
```

So for instance, at the cell (row,40), if its 8 NOT IN PROGRESS, the 8 will be replaced by george.

and then next row

Comment: By "smaller and equal to 5" I assume you mean "less than or equal to 5", and by "bigger and equal to 5" I guess you mean "greater than", but please clarify. You might want to look into a solution that doesn't use VBA. You might get it with just a formula: `if(and(h5<=5, k5<=5, n5<=5, q5<=5, t5<=5, w5<=5, z5<=5, ac<=5, af<=5), "OK IN PROGRESS", handle other cases here)`. The "other cases" are the more difficult part, but I think it could be done (possibly employing some helper cells).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick VBA solution, if that's what you need:

```
Sub ProcessRows()
    Dim rSt As Integer, rEn As Integer, val As Integer, r As Integer
    Dim cSt As Integer, cEn As Integer, c As Integer
    Dim name As String, inProgressMsg As String, notInProgressMsg1 As String, notInProgressMsg2 As String
    rSt = 5
    rEn = 3004
    val = 5
    cSt = 8
    cEn = 32
    inProgressMsg = "OK IN PROGRESS"
    notInProgressMsg2 = "NOT IN PROGRESS"

    For r = rSt To rEn
        notInProgressMsg1 = ""
        For c = cSt To cEn Step 3
            If Cells(r, c).Value > val Then
                name = ReplaceNumberWithName(c)
                notInProgressMsg1 = notInProgressMsg1 & name & " "
            End If
        Next c

        If notInProgressMsg1 = "" Then
            Cells(r, 40).Value = inProgressMsg
        Else
            Cells(r, 40).Value = notInProgressMsg1 & notInProgressMsg2
        End If
    Next r
End Sub

Function ReplaceNumberWithName(n As Integer) As String
    ReplaceNumberWithName = "NO_NAME_FOUND"

    If n = 8 Then
        ReplaceNumberWithName = "george"
    ElseIf n = 11 Then
        ReplaceNumberWithName = "cindy"
    ElseIf n = 14 Then
        ReplaceNumberWithName = "jennifer"
    ElseIf n = 17 Then
        ReplaceNumberWithName = "lucas"
    ElseIf n = 20 Then
        ReplaceNumberWithName = "apple"
    ElseIf n = 23 Then
        ReplaceNumberWithName = "jeff"
    ElseIf n = 26 Then
        ReplaceNumberWithName = "may"
    ElseIf n = 29 Then
        ReplaceNumberWithName = "kevin"
    ElseIf n = 32 Then
        ReplaceNumberWithName = "oscar"
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: HIII NEIZAN! YOU ARE AWSOME! THANK YOU SO MUCH! IT WORKS!